# java.lang.NullPointerException when I create an array that uses values of an other class

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have a class Student with 3 attributes,

```java
public static class Student {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public int studentnumber;
}
```

that I want to initialize in an array in a suitable loop in an external class. The attributes of each student are to be initialized using user input (for that I have a Terminal class):

```java
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberofstudents = Terminal.askInt("How many students to you want to enter?  ");
        Student[] array = new Student[numberofstudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberofstudents; i++) {
            array[i].firstname = Terminal.askString("Enter student's firstname ");
            array[i].lastname = Terminal.askString("Enter student's lastname ");
            array[i].studentnumbere = Terminal.askString("Enter student's number ");
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I initialize a value of the Array,

```java
array[i].firstname = Terminal.askString("Student's firstname ");
```

I get the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array index with a `new Student()` before you can update the value at this array index. By default, `Student[]` contains `null` at each index and therefore you will get `NullPointerException` if you try to perform any operation (e.g. assigning a value to `array[i].firstname`) on it without initializing it will a non-null value.

```
for(int i = 0;i<numberofstudents;i++){
    array[i] = new Student();
    array[i].firstname = Terminal.askString("Enter student's firstname ");
    array[i].lastname = Terminal.askString("Enter student's lastname ");
    array[i].studentnumbere = Terminal.askString("Enter student's number ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Student` array is empty! It has a length of your input, but has no student objects in it.

Create a new `Student`, and add it to the list first!

```
for(int i = 0;i<numberofstudents;i++) {
    array[i] = new Student();
    array[i].firstname = Terminal.askString("Enter student's firstname ");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each items of an array with `new Student();`

It's better to have a normal Student class (NOT static one). It seems that you want to hold total student count number so you can only have that variable as a static attribute (`private static int studentNumber`), and whenever you create a new instance of Student just `++` the value of `studentNumber`. In this case you don't need to get students number each time.

And it's better to have `private` attributes and access them via **getters** and **setters** rather than `public` attributes.

```java
public class Student {
    private static int studentNumber = 0;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long studentId;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Long studentId) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        studentNumber++; // increase students count after each initialization
    }

    public static int getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public static void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) {
        Student.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
}
```

In your Main class, you need to initialize each items of an array with new Student();

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfStudents = Terminal.askInt("How many students to you want to enter?  ");

        // this line just create an empty array that can hold Student objcets in it
        Student[] array = new Student[numberOfStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // you need to initialize each items of an array with new()
            array[i] = new Student(Terminal.askString("Enter student's firstname "),
                    Terminal.askString("Enter student's lastname "),
                    Terminal.askString("Enter student's ID "));
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to follow indentation rules, and start all classes name with Uppercase (***Main***, ***Student***, ***Terminal***, etc.). Finally use camel-case (***studentNumbers***, ***firstName***, ***lastName***).

Comment: It's not a good practice code, and I just tried to mention some concepts to improve your future codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *constructor* with three fields to the `Student` class and simplify your code as follows:

```java
public static class Student {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public int studentNumber;

    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, int studentNumber) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfStudents =
            Terminal.askInt("How many students to you want to enter?  ");
    Student[] array = new Student[numberOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        array[i] = new Student(
                Terminal.askString("Enter student's firstname "),
                Terminal.askString("Enter student's lastname "),
                Terminal.askString("Enter student's number "));
    }
}
```